# how can I crop a sector of a circle on an image in python using scikit image

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I am using scikit image for python 3.5. I'd like to crop a sector of a circle and save it as a different image.

All I have is center of the circle(cx,cy), radius r, 2 coordinates(x1,y1),(x2,y2) on the perimeter of the circle, and the equations of 2 lines of a sector.

If it is entire circle, i can use the circle equation and blacken the rest of the image but as it is a sector, I am facing a problem.

Comment: Can you include the code you have now?

Comment: I dont have a code but can you guide me with  a general idea so i can write it.Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the drawing functions from `skimage.draw`, you can construct a circle and a polygon and intersect the two to obtain a slice:[image]

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random image
image = np.random.random((200, 200))

# --- coordinate specification

r0, c0 = 100, 70  # circle center (row, column)
R = 100  # circle radius

theta0 = np.deg2rad(20)  # angle #1 for arc
theta1 = np.deg2rad(40)  # angle #2 for arc

# Above, I provide two angles, but you can also just give the two
# coordinates below directly

r1, c1 = r0 - 1.5 * R * np.sin(theta0), c0 + 1.5 * R * np.cos(theta0)  # arc coord #1
r2, c2 = r0 - 1.5 * R * np.sin(theta1), c0 + 1.5 * R * np.cos(theta1)  # arc coord #2

# --- mask calculation

mask_circle = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=bool)
mask_poly = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=bool)

rr, cc = draw.circle(r0, c0, R, shape=mask_circle.shape)
mask_circle[rr, cc] = 1

rr, cc = draw.polygon([r0, r1, r2, r0],
                      [c0, c1, c2, c0], shape=mask_poly.shape)
mask_poly[rr, cc] = 1

mask = mask_circle & mask_poly

plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: "mask=mask_circle & mask_poly" is giving only a triangle but not the sector

Comment: What do you mean?  That's the intersection between the polygon and the circle, which is a sector.

Comment: i figured where I am going wrong. now i have the sector  but how can i apply the mask to my image of type uint8

Comment: I masked the image aswell but not sure how to save unmasked part of image to a separate file. 
image_mask = mask_circle & mask_poly
mk=numpy.logical_not(image_mask)
image[mk]=0
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

This gives me the blackened portion aswell.

Comment: Would you like to save only the rectangle bounding the masked area?

Comment: No, I just need to save the sector part of the image.

Comment: So, given that images are rectangular, how would you like to save it?  Do you want a transparent PNG?

Comment: I understand. with the rectangular boxes i am trying to save all the sectors with different names iteratively but I am getting the same image for all the files. 
for K in range(7):
imagevar=image #original image
rr, cc = draw.polygon([r0, r1[K], r1[K+1], r0],[c0, c1[K], c1[K+1], c0], shape=mask_poly.shape)# have different coordinates
mask_poly[rr, cc] = 1
image_mask = mask_circle & mask_poly
mk=numpy.logical_not(image_mask)
imagevar[mk]=0
path='directory'
NewfileNameToSave = path+fileNameToSave + '_'+ str(K+1) + '.jpg'
io.imsave(NewfileNameToSave,imagevar)

where am I going wrong